# Limit comments amount in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

How to limit comments amount in WP_Query ? I'm using `add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_filter');` and

```
    $query->set('orderby','date');
    $query->set('order','DESC');
```

to limit WP search query. I would like to limit the amount of search posts relative to the amount of comments they have. For example search for only those posts that have a number of comments in the range of 0 to 15.

Answer (score 0):

I have used appropriate WP_Query parameters to do this task:

```
$from=0;
$to=50;
$meta=array();
    array_push($meta,array('key' => 'comments_amount','value' => $from,'compare' => '>=','type' => 'numeric'));
    array_push($meta,array('key' => 'comments_amount','value' => $to,'compare' => '<=','type' => 'numeric'));
$query->set('meta_query',$meta);
```

You can write it as a function and then call by:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchFilter');
```

Passing $query as a function parameter.